# GitHub contributions from local e-mail address not showing up

Tags: git, github

On my GitHub page, contributions committed using a fake local e-mail address (ending in @mycomputer.local or similar) don't get listed on the contributions graph.

[GitHub's help page](https://help.github.com/articles/why-are-my-contributions-not-showing-up-on-my-profile/) says it's not possible to get these commits to show up even if the fake e-mail address is added to the profile. I changed the e-mail for future commits, but is there any way to get the earlier commits to show up?
Or an alternate way to [rewrite the commit history](https://help.github.com/articles/changing-author-info/), that doesn't require up/downloading and recreating the entire repository.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am afraid you are out of luck.

GitHub states that,

> Generic email addresses--such as jane@computer.local--cannot be added to GitHub accounts. If you use such an email for your commits, the commits will not be linked to your GitHub profile and will not show up in your contributions graph.

So, if you are not willing to / can't rewrite your history, and GitHub is not willing to amend the above rule, there is no way to accomplish what you seek.